# Difference between type 'Function' and type '() => {}' in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

If I'm declaring a variable `func` that will have a function assigned to it with Typescript, I've seen two different ways of doing this:

1) `let func: Function`

2) `let func: () => {}`

What's the difference? Is second for arrow functions only, and the first for all non-arrow functions?

Comment: `let func: Function` is valid for all kid of functions. `let func: () => {}` defines a function signature that doesn't accept parameters and returns an `object`

Comment: @Eldar That should be an answer.

Comment: Actually, `() => {}` is a void function, @Eldar.

Comment: `()=> void` is the void function.

Comment: @HereticMonkey if used as a value it is a void returning function.  If used as a type it is a function that returns an object (with no known properties). A bit funny that the value `() => {}` is not assignable to the type `()=> {}`  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=30&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAZgdgXBAFASggXgHwQN4F91KqY4S4DcQA

Comment: The *type* `() => {}` is a function that requires no arguments and returns anything except for `null` or `undefined` (assuming `--strictNullChecks` is on, which it should be).  The *value* `() => {}` is a no-arg void-returning function.  In `let func: () => {}` we're talking about the type, not the value.  EDIT: yeah, what @TitianCernicova-Dragomir said.

Answer (score 3):

`let func`: Function is valid for all kid of functions. `let func: () => {}` defines a function signature that doesn't accept parameters and returns an object

```
let anyFunction: Function;

let dummyFunction: () => {};

let voidFunction: () => void;


function dummy() {

}

function dummy2() {
 return {} 
}

function dumm3(arg:number) {
  return {}
}

// error dummy has ne return type.
dummyFunction = dummy;

// its ok dummy has void return type 
voidFunction = dummy;

// its ok
dummyFunction = dummy2;

//error dumm3 has argument
dummyFunction = dumm3;

// its all ok
anyFunction = dumm3;
anyFunction = dummy2;
anyFunction = dummy;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=36&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAhgdgngMQK4wMZgJYHsYC4LJqY4DcAUGaJACZIC2diK62eEAFAJQQC8AfBADeAX3KVwEAG5YM1Qixz4uvAdNliyAM2bEYEWgzjLBZCBDLCK2oq331GAJmOmATuCQu9I85a07bBnQAzOxQLgDmuDD0AEYgLtwmZm5gHl6WvgD0mRDxLlgudoYQABZQAM4QMCAQKWkQYHAADiAAdGSBTDY4vEWMYtkQGGCVWADWfXClFVIy1LXung3NNWRqcv49PJMDOcOjYx32XQp6250Ou3kFfUHTlWHh9CAwYEeG8rq9gUG7QyPQYDACDjMiwE5fc72X5g+CfWxQwyXWEQhE7ChAA)